# Keras: Embedding and LSTM layers for POS-Tagging task

Tags: nlp, keras, lstm, embedding, pos-tagger

I have a list of tagged sentences. I transformed each of them in the following way:

- For each **word**, get the relative one-hot encoding form (a vector of dimension `input_dim`);
- Insert a pre-padding as explained in the example below;
- Split each sentence in `len(sentence)` sub-sentences, using a window of size `time_steps` (to get the context for the prediction of the next word).

For example, using `time_steps=2`, a single sentence `["this", "is", 
"an", "example"]` is transformed in:

```
[
    [one_hot_enc("empty_word"), one_hot_enc("empty_word")],
    [one_hot_enc("empty_word"), one_hot_enc("this")],
    [one_hot_enc("this"), one_hot_enc("is")],
    [one_hot_enc("is"), one_hot_enc("an")],
]
```

At the end, considering the sub-sentences as an unique list, the shape of the train data `X_train` is `(num_samples, time_steps, input_dim)`, where:

- `input_dim`: the size of my vocabulary;
- `time_steps`: the length of sequence to use into LSTM;
- `num_samples`: the number of samples (sub-sentences);

Now, I want to use an `Embedding` layer, in order to map each word to a smaller an continuous dimensional space, and an `LSTM`, in which I use the contexts build as above.

I tried something like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(time_steps, input_dim)))
model.add(Embedding(input_dim, embedding_size, input_length=time_steps))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Dense(output_dim))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

But gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
```

What I missing? There is some logical error in what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply remove the Input layer and let the embedding layer be the first layer of the network.
Or you can construct the Input layer by removing the "input_dim" like

```
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(time_steps, )))
```